# App is crashing after upgrading gradle "gradle-4.1-all.zip"

Tags: react-native, gradle, genymotion

I have upgraded my "gradle-wrapper.properties" to use "gradle-4.1-all.zip". When I am trying to build it's successful but app is crashing in both Genymotion as well as in device.
I tried cleaning my node modules but still it's not working.

Versions - "react-native": "0.47.1", "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12"

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mjb"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is the root build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

Comment: Did u update `buildToolsVersion` in build.gradle? that should be `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"`

Comment: Yes it is "buildToolsVersion   = "27.0.3". I tried with "buildToolsVersion "23.0.1""  as well nothing worked so far.

Comment: can i see your build.gradle file ?